# Displaying a Game-board from a txt file by reading in each char

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to display

```
X  XXXXXXX  XXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXX
X XXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   XXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX      XXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXF        -----      XX           XXXX
XXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXX  XXXXX          FXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXX  XXX XXXX  XXXX--XXXX
XXXXXXXX    XXXXXX  XXXXXXXX   XXX--XXXX
XXXXXXX  XXXXXXX    XXXXXXXXX       XXXX
XXXXXX  XXXXXXXX  XXXXX XXXXX     --XXXX
       XXX   XXX  XX XX XXXXXXXXXX--XXXX
       XXX  XXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX--XXXX
XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX  XX-          XXX--XXXX
XXX  XXXXXXXXXXX  XX----XXXX      --XXXX
XXXX XXXXXF           XXXXXX     XX$XXXX
XXXXXXXXXXX          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I am using, Where ROWS = 15 and COLS = 40

```
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
{
       for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
       {
            board[row][col] = inFile.get();
            cout << board[row][col];
       }
}
```

It is essential that this table is stored in the character array. Though when I display the table the final row doesn't display fully.

Why isn't the table coming out correctly?

Comment: I would assume that `inFile.get()` is not returning what you think it should. Have you used a debugger to verify that it's bring in what you think? Are you accounting for new lines?

Comment: There is probably an issue with new lines. But I'm not sure how to account for that.

Comment: After you get `COLS` characters, presumably the next one would be a `\n`, so you'd want to ignore it.

Comment: I you are using Visual Studio I  highly recommend you spend 20 minutes and follow this debugging tutorial: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger-cpp?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably trying to store the newline characters in the `board` array. You need to add an additional `.get()` after every inner loop to grab the newline so it won't get pulled into your array:

```
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
{
     for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
     {
          board[row][col] = inFile.get();
          cout << board[row][col];
     }
     // Pull out the newline
     inFile.get();
     cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you.